# How can I compare objects only when they are created from the same parent object?

Tags: rust

I want to compare `Obj`s only when they are created from the same `Parent` object, and it works, but only one way: if you switch the order of comparison, it does not.

Here's the minimal code:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Parent {
    val: u64,
}

impl Parent {
    pub fn new(v: u64) -> Parent {
        Parent { val: v }
    }

    pub fn child(&self, v: u64) -> Child {
        Child {
            val: v,
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

struct Child<'a> {
    val: u64,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a Parent>,
}

impl<'a> Child<'a> {
    pub fn compare(&'a self, l: &Obj<'a>, r: &Obj<'a>) -> bool {
        l.val == r.val
    }

    pub fn obj(&'a self, v: u64) -> Obj<'a> {
        Obj {
            val: v,
            child: self,
        }
    }
}

struct Obj<'a> {
    val: u64,
    child: &'a Child<'a>,
}

impl<'a> PartialEq<Obj<'a>> for Obj<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Obj<'a>) -> bool {
        self.child.compare(self, other)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let parent = Parent::new(1);
    let child = parent.child(2);
    let obj1 = child.obj(3);
    let obj2 = child.obj(3);

    // those are from the same parent, this sould work (and works).
    assert!(obj1 == obj2);
    assert!(obj2 == obj1);

    let parent2 = Parent::new(1);
    let child2 = parent2.child(2);
    let obj12 = child2.obj(3);
    let obj22 = child2.obj(3);

    // this works fine too
    assert!(obj12 == obj22);
    assert!(obj22 == obj12);

    // those are from different parents

    //assert!(obj1 == obj12); // that line DOES NOT compile, which is exactly what I want!
    assert!(obj12 == obj1); // but that line suddenly DOES compile.
}
```

How can I change the code so that the last line won't compile?

Comment: I don't think lifetimes are the correct way to encode this. Since the second parent is defined after the first parent, it's lifetime is strictly within the lifetime of the first parent. Any lifetime-checks you can think of will still allow any object with the second lifetime to be used in a situation where something of the first lifetime is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll happily explain the lifetime approach, but it doesn't seem to be viable.

When is `X` a subtype of `Y` (denoted `X <: Y`)?

The question posed for generics involves **variance**.

The variance answers the question: for a generic type `G<X>`, what does `X <: Y` mean for the relation of `G<X>` to `G<Y>`.

- Covariance: `X <: Y` => `G<X> <: G<Y>`
- Invariance: `X == Y` => `G<X> <: G<Y>`
- Contravariance: `X <: Y` => `G<Y> <: G<X>`

`Cell<X>` is invariant w.r.t `X`, so `phantom: PhantomData<Cell<&'a Parent>>,` makes `Child<'a>` **invariant** w.r.t `'a`.

`PhantomData` is a way to trick you to talk about variance by just describing it in types you already know.

This appears to work, but not so fast, because we can create a situation where the lifetimes are totally equal, and then the test compiles again!

```
let (parent, parent2) = (Parent::new(1), Parent::new(1));
let (child, child2) = (parent.child(2), parent2.child(2));
// Plan is foiled!!
```

Comment: Is this stating that using lifetimes is not a feasible way of solving this problem? If so, you way wish to explicitly state that.

Comment: I don't know that, but this isn't enough. This answer was just a comment that got too long :)

Comment: @bluss: I remember toying around with this and nmatsakis had warned me against trying to abuse lifetimes as *brands*: the Rust language makes no guarantee about its lifetime inference in terms of backward compatibility; that two parents *today* can already be created with the same lifetime means we are lucky the plan gets foiled now instead of down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer that could excite you or scare you to death: *Use monads*.

Specifically the [ST Monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad/ST). Unfortunately, I can't explain it to you, but it is my understanding that it could be useful in this case. Let us know if you figure it out!

I was shown this [for my own project](https://github.com/shepmaster/sxd-document/issues/8):

> You can replicate InvariantLifetime, which is what is actually done in [the BTreeMap implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/474c6e0ae47578b3e608c893e18bc83798b565aa/src/libcollections/btree/map.rs#L615-L628). The reason I say it's very heavyweight is that the only way to make its properties useful is to require each document to be created (or at least, accessed) within a closure.

The pragmatic solution is to not attempt to make these compile-time errors, but just include the parent pointer in the comparison:

```
#[derive(Debug,Copy,Clone,PartialEq)]
struct Parent {
    val: u64,
}

impl Parent {
    fn child(&self) -> Child { Child { parent: self, val: self.val } }
}

#[derive(Debug,Copy,Clone)]
struct Child<'a> {
    parent: &'a Parent,
    val: u64,
}

impl<'a> PartialEq for Child<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Child<'a>) -> bool {
        (self.parent as *const _, self.val) == (other.parent as *const _, other.val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (p1, p2) = (Parent { val: 42 }, Parent { val: 42 });
    let p1_c1 = p1.child();
    let p1_c2 = p1.child();
    let p2_c1 = p2.child();

    println!("{}", p1_c1 == p1_c2);
    println!("{}", p1_c1 == p2_c1);
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's some extra info for the lifetime. Note that `InvariantLifetime<'a>` is exactly `PhantomData<Cell<&'a .. >>` that I mentioned.